# Images not loading using oat++

Tags: oat++

I'm doing a simple GET and loading a image.

```
ENDPOINT("GET", 
            "/images/{image}", 
            get_image,
            PATH(String, image))
    {
        std::ifstream image_file(www_path +
                                 std::string("/images/") +
                                 std::string(image->c_str()));
        if (image_file.is_open() == false)
        {
            return createResponse(Status::CODE_404, "Not Found\n");
        }
        std::stringstream buffer;
        buffer << image_file.rdbuf();
        image_file.close();
        return createResponse(Status::CODE_200, buffer.str().c_str());
    }
```

I'm opening the image and creating a response but the image shows broken with 0x0 pixels, I tried to check the buffer to see if the image is there and it was, all of it.